# Serialize Boolean to "1" and "0" instead of "true" and "false"

Tags: java, serialization, boolean

I can't find any method on the `Boolean` class to serialize a Boolean to "1" and "0" instead of "true" and "false".

Is there any native function to do that ? If not, what is the best way (most optimized way) ?

Update: I indeed mean to produce a `String` out of a `Boolean`.

Comment: What method *serialized* a `Boolean` to "true" and "false"? Or are you simply talking about producing a `String` from a `Boolean`?

Comment: Let `b` be a boolean: `int i = b ? 1 : 0;`.

Comment: @Matthieu, You have more than 10 questions you haven't accepted. ;)

Comment: @Kevin: careful! He's talking about about `Boolean`, in which case `b` could be `null`!

Comment: @Joachim: Ah! Very keen.

Comment: @Kevin do you mean `int i == b ? 1 : 0;` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*If* you're talking about producing a `String` from a given `Boolean`, then no, there is no built-in method that produces "0" or "1", but you can easily write it:

```
public static String toNumeralString(final Boolean input) {
  if (input == null) {
    return "null";
  } else {
    return input.booleanValue() ? "1" : "0";
  }
}
```

Depending on your use case, it might be more appropriate to let it throw a `NullPointerException` if `input` is null. If that's the case for you, then you can reduce the method to the second `return` line alone.

Comment: seems you missed the data type in your method

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: indeed I did, thanks for the heads-up. Fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [CompareTo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Boolean%29):

```
public static Integer booleanToInteger(Boolean bool)
{
    if(bool == null) return null;
    else return bool.compareTo(Boolean.FALSE);
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't encourage this, as it's pretty obfuscated and non-obvious. And *if* you do, I'd use `Boolean.FALSE` as the argument, in order to skip the auto-boxing.

Comment: ... and obscure / obfuscated code is less likely to be optimizable by the JIT compiler.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, whether or not it should be encouraged it does explicitly answer both my and the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to serialise to a char you can do

```
public static char toChar(final Boolean b) {
    return b == null ? '?' : b ? '1' : '0';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but just throwing it out. you can use your own Decorator class.

Comment: A Decorator Design pattern lets you customize your output in different way. You can decorate your `boolean` to a `0` and `1` value.

Comment: Did you see where the OP asked for the "most optimized" solution?  Do you think that decorators qualify?

Answer (score -2):

Use Thrift API:

```
TSerializer serializer = new TSerializer(new TSimpleJSONProtocol.Factory());
String json = serializer.toString(object);
```

It will boolean to 0 or 1 instead of true/false.

Comment: Are you serious? Installing a whole library, using 2 objects with factories and all just to turn a string into a boolean…