# How can I replace "true" and "false" in java?

Tags: java, replace, boolean

I need change the values for boolean variables, for example:

Change this:

```
boolean x = true;
System.out.print(x); //console: true
```

For this:

```
boolean x = true;
System.out.print(x); //console: 1
```

This is my code:

```
final boolean[] BOOLEAN_VALUES = new boolean [] {true,false};
for (boolean a : BOOLEAN_VALUES) {
                boolean x = negation(a);
                String chain = a+"\t"+x;
                chain.replaceAll("true", "1").replaceAll("false","0");
                System.out.println(chain);
        }

negation is a method:

    public static boolean negation(boolean a){
            return !a;
        }
```

As you can see, I try using `.replaceAll`, but its not working, when I executed, this is the output:

> ```
>     a ¬a
> ----------------
> true  false
> false true
> ```

I really don't see my error.

Comment: `x = !x`; `x = false`?

Comment: I didnt get you but if you are talking about printing "1" instead of printing "true", you could use something like this:
`System.out.print(x ? 1:0);`

Comment: `System.out.println(x ? 1 : 0);`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serialize Boolean to "1" and "0" instead of "true" and "false"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340766/serialize-boolean-to-1-and-0-instead-of-true-and-false)

Comment: hmm i found the solution, just it is missing a line:   [code]chain = chain.replaceAll("true", "1").replaceAll("false","0");[/code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i found the solution, i just missed matching the variable:

```
chain = chain.replaceAll("true", "1").replaceAll("false","0");
```

Now this is solved, thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println(x ? 1 : 0);` should do the trick , basically 1 if true, and 0 otherwise

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways:

The `if-else` one, which checks if `x` is `true` or `false`.

```
if (x) {
    System.out.println(1);
} else {
    System.out.println(0);
}
```

**Note:** `if (x)` is the same as `if (x == true)`.

The ternary one:

```
System.out.println(x ? 1 : 0);
```

Which checks if `x` is `true` if so, it prints `1` else it prints `0`. I recommend the ternary one as it's shorter and helps for code clarity.